# Is Visual Studio 2012 backwards compatible with Visual Studio 2010 in a team environment

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have read that projects created in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 will need no modifications when opening with VS2012.

I have a team of about 4 developers, both working on the same project using source control, will it be an issue if say only 1 or 2 of them upgrades to VS2012 first, while the rest still stays on VS2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *should* be backward compatible.  Is it guaranteed to be in all circumstances?  Well, VS2012 is still pretty new, so your mileage may vary.

The documentation may claim that it works.  People may say that they've had no problems with it.  You may even try it on your team and have no problems with it.  But are you willing to bet the stability of the project on it?

As you can imagine, there's really no "correct" answer to this question.  But some things to consider may be:

- Pro: Keeping the code running in a diverse set of tools and environments tends to keep the code nimble, ensuring that it's not relying on the environment too much and is self-sustaining.
- Con: Having different setups on developer workstations opens the door wide for "it works on my machine" syndrome.

It's your call.

Answer (score 2):

In my company we 're currently using a mixture or Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 clients for Development, we use Team Foundation Server 2010 for the repositories, we had no problems so far.

This is just my personal experience, our main solution have about 20 different projects in VB and C# and WebSites, no problems at all.

My 2 cents...